# Can't add different element's id to state array on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to set the ids of svg circles to state on click.

I expected that the ids, let's say 1, 2 and 3, would be set to the state array: `[1, 2, 3]`

What happens is that when I click on circle 1, the array looks like this: `[1]` as expected. When I go on and click on circle 2 the array contains `[2]` and not `[1, 2]` as expected. If I keep going on and click on circle 1 again, the array looks like `[1, 1]`. So the array always contains one or more of the same items, but refuses to push different items, like `[1, 3]`

I tried to add the ids to the state array using concat, push and the spread operator, all with the same unexpected result as described above.

I set the initial state in the constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { array: [] };
}
```

and tried to add items to the state array using concat:

```
test = (e) => {
    const currentArray = this.state.array;
    const newArray = currentArray.concat(e.currentTarget.__data__.id);
    this.setState({ array: newArray }, () => console.log(this.state.array));
};
```

and the spread operator:

```
test = (e) => {
    let newArray = this.state.array.splice();
    newArray.push(e.currentTarget.__data__.id);
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        array: [...prevState.array, newArray ]
    }), () => console.log(this.state.array));
};
```

this is the circle element:

```
<circle onClick={this.test.bind(this)}/>
```

I managed to get this working by setting the array as a variable and push the ids into it on click. But with React, it seems to make sense to do this using state. I hope you can tell me what I am doing wrong.

UPDATE - mapping of circles in parent component:

```
const nodes = this.state.nodes.map( (node) => {
    return (
        <Node
            nodeClass={this.props.nodeClass}
            data={node}
            label={node.label}
            key={node.id}
        />);
    });
```

Comment: Thank you Liam, I tried your example. I got an error when using `currentTarget`, I also tried `this.props.data.id`, but with the same unexpected results. I've tried a lot of examples, I don't understand why it won't work. I also updated the question with the code for the mapping

Comment: Yes because you're not passing the id correctly, I don't see the circle onClick in your map code

Comment: `data` is an object. `data.id` contains the id. Should I move the test function up to the parent component and set the onClick in the mapping part?

Comment: Are you getting id in the test method correctly? and also I think you should use spread operator like this :-  array: [...this.state.array , newElement].

Comment: The problem can be seen in this pen: https://codepen.io/vialito/pen/aYPqqV. I tried to move the test function up to its parent component, but I have not been able to get the id so far. Looking at the undefined console log, it does seem to go into the right direction though

Comment: I've got it working by adding `id={node.id}` to the circle's html. In the test function I can then acces the id with `e.target.id`. I still wonder, isn't it possible to get the id without adding it to html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing the id correctly, you need to move up your `test` function to `Graph` component and create a `constructor` with `array state`

then map the data inside SVG like

```
<svg className="graph" width={width}  height={height} >
              {this.props.data.nodes.map( (node) =>   
                <g  onClick={this.test.bind(this, node)}>

            <Node
                data={node}
                name={node.name}
                key={node.id}
            />
                </g>)}
                <g>
                     {this.props.data.links.map( (link,i) => 
                <Link
                    key={link.target+i}
                    data={link}

                />)}
                </g>
            </svg>
```

> The important thing that we did above that we passed the node with
>   onClick bind

```
onClick={this.test.bind(this, node)}
```

then call the test function I added some extra code to avoid repeating for that clicked id

```
test = (node) => {
  console.log(node.id, 'look here this coming from test function')
  if(this.state.array.indexOf(node.id) !== -1){
     this.setState(prevState => ({ 
        array: this.state.array.filter(d => d.id !== node.id)
    }));// this will not repeat the clicked id
  }else{
      this.setState(prevState => ({ 
        array: [...prevState.array, node.id]
    }));
  }
};
```

here's full code

https://codepen.io/Liamm12/pen/NYeOyW?editors=0011

Comment: Thank you for your help and the added code Liam. That's exactly what I was looking for. Now I understand what's wrong